# Do there exists "natural" unclosed subspaces $X_1$ and $X_2$ of $\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{N})$ such that $V=X_1\oplus X_2$?

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I'm considering $\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{N})$ with the supremum-norm. I am interested in natural examples (like $X_1$ equal to the space of sequences that eventually vanish), as the mere existence of such $X_i$'s is obvious with the AOC. I would also be interested to know if there are similar decompositions for normed spaces other than $\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{N})$.